# Flutter iOS archive release getting 'xx plugin.h' file not found error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, flutter

Following the steps at [Preparing an iOS App for Release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios), I got to Create Build Archive and the following command ran successfully:

```
flutter build ios
```

However, when I opened the project Runner in Xcode to create the archive, I get an error in the `GeneratePluginRegistrant.m` file:

> 'package_info/PackageInfoPlugin.h' file not found

I thought that maybe it was the fault of the plugin so I removed that plugin from my project. But then I got an error on the next one:

> 'path_provider/PathProviderPlugin.h' file not found

[image]

Here are my flutter doctor results:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.32.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

What do I need to do to resolve this problem?

### Update 1

I'm pretty sure I checked the Swift option when I created the project, but I'm not using any custom Swift code, so that isn't a necessity.

These GitHub issues look the same: [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20564) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21073). However, running the following command (as suggested in the comments) didn't change the error message:

```
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

### Update 2

I started a new Flutter project (with Swift support) and added the following dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  sqflite: ^1.0.0
  package_info: ^0.4.0+2
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.4
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
```

But there were no errors and I was able to run the Archive.

Now I don't know where to look for the error in my original app.

Comment: Hmm no concrete answers to this. I have the same problem with a different .h file.

Comment: Did you succeed? Just by creating a new project?
I am also having the same problem. Build for the physical device or generic device works fine, just Archive fails with header problem.

Comment: @Locke, It worked for me to create a new project and copy the parts over. I don't know what the original problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly an ideal answer, but the way I solved it was to create a new project with the same name and then bit by bit copy all of the pieces over from the old app, testing that it builds in Xcode all along the way. By the very end it still built and I was able to make the archive.

Apparently there is something about new Flutter projects that don't contain whatever was causing the error before.

Comment: I saw a comment somewhere about running `flutter create` to fix missing files. I don't know if that would apply here, but it might help.

Comment: @genericUser, I'm talking about `flutter create .` not `flutter clean`.

Comment: Happened to me either, 2 hours of googling and try different solution still didn't work, until I got my gut to follow your solution (Creating new project). And yeah, the error is gone, I think that new project had something that flutter upgrade didn't have.
Thanks @suragch

Comment: If I were to do this again I might just try deleting the `ios` folder and running `flutter create .` to rebuild it before completely creating a new project, but it's really not that hard to create a new project too.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to clean the repositories with **CMD + Shift + K**, then generate a **clean flutter** and then **get flutter packages**.

This was solved and generated the .ipa satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

Restarted Xcode and reopened my project by .workspace (not .project) file. Everything started to archive again.